# Is this circuit connected right?

Tags: arduino-uno, led, lcd

I want to create something similar to an article I read a few months ago about the effects of Dopamine. Dopamine is known as the feel-good neurotransmitter; the brain releases it when we eat food that we crave, contributing to pleasure and satisfaction as part of the reward system. I want to use this reward method for breaking habits and creating new ones. I saw someone on youtube make a Dopamine box, very similar to what I was thinking (I left it down below), but I think it had a few design flaws.

So how it works, the lights will be dimmed (so it’s not annoying) and default red, the screen in the center will read the list of activities you have set for yourself that you want to be completed. When you complete a task, you will flip a switch on the housing side; this will toggle some lights to go from red to green and give you the reward system. Along with the lights turning green, the box will play a sound, similar to when you win a game or get a kill, again triggering the dopamine release.

The LCD will display a message, something like "keep going"  or "Don't quit."
The LED is for the green and red lights mentioned above, and the piezo is for a buzzer to play a sound to congratulate you for finishing a task.

Down below, I left a circuit I [made in TinkerCad](https://www.tinkercad.com/embed/9EYfcPv1XsX?editbtn=1). I am very new to this, and I would like if someone could look at my connections and tell me if I have connected them correctly.

TinkerCad Link- https://www.tinkercad.com/things/9EYfcPv1XsX

[image: Capture from Tinkercad showing circuit.]

Comment: <iframe width="725" height="453" src="https://www.tinkercad.com/embed/9EYfcPv1XsX?editbtn=1" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Comment: Please provide a normal link to your tinkercad circuit, not an embed link. Also please put an image of the circuit directly in your question. That way the question will stay valid, even when the link becomes invalid

Comment: Have you tested the circuit in tinkercad? Does it work? If everything works as intended, then the circuit should be correct

Comment: if the circuit works, then it is probably connected correctly

Comment: Ah, I see 1 problem: Your code doesn't use the Neopixel ring, but why did you connect its data pin to D2 together with the LCD. The data pin of the Neopixel ring needs an own digital output pin.

Comment: @chrisl sorry, I added the link in the post, and I left it down below in this reply. Thanks again!

link- https://www.tinkercad.com/things/9EYfcPv1XsX

Comment: @chrisl I am very new with TinkerCad; how do I test it?